# Python pygbag web-app without using the local server

Tags: python, pygbag

after trying pygbag for the first time I successfully managed to run a pygame program on the browser. However, I still dont completely understand why the program must use my local server to work.

So I would very appreciate an explanation.

I tried to run the game without using any server but only with my html file, but when I try to just open my index.html file I get "Error occurred: Failed to fetch" Error.

I tried to open the index.html file instead of using my local server but it didnt work... I wanted it to work the same as before.

I also tried to upload it to a repl.it host but I really dont know how this the python-script combined with the html and the apk works all together. Im very confused.

Comment: i would suggest to follow that issue https://github.com/pygame-web/pygbag/issues/77   The feature you want will ultimately arrive with initial release  and for replit look there https://github.com/pygame-web/pygbag/issues/110

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your local server does not support SSL and does not provide a correct Certificate.

The reason it works on http://localhost ( nb: not 127.0.0.1 ! ) is that internet browsers drop security ONLY for that address.

To host a pygame-ce wasm game you need to use an SSL enabled server (itch/github pages/...) or you need to pack your game entirely to HTML ( but that feature will not be available until stable release ).

Another way would be to replicate the whole pygame-web cdn on your http-only server and handle updates yourself ( but still you would not get multiplayer  network / camera. One thing still working in that case would be esp8266+telemetrix which is usefull for fablabs.